# Creating a List<T> that matches items first, then adding in the rest using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This should be an easy one.

I got a LINQ problem that I hope someone can help me out. Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID {get; set;}        // Primary key
    public int CategoryID {get; set; }      // Foreign key
}
```

So let's say that I need to find all products in the `List<Products>.Where(p => p.CategoryID == 2)`, and then list the rest of the products.

Another words, any Products that matches the CategoryID I need to have them listed first, and then the rest of Products that doesn't match.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try following : List<Products>Select(p => order = p.CategoryID == 2? 1 : 2).OrderBy(x => x.order)

Comment: in what format do you need the outcome? simply one list again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Except` method:

```
var categoryTwoItems = products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == 2);
var otherItems = products.Except(categoryTwoItems);
```

If you want to order all the items by category Id, but have those with `CategoryId == 2` come first, you could do something like this:

```
var catId2First = products
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CategoryID == 2)
    .ThenBy(p => p.CategoryID)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Except, and use 2 queries.

```
var categoryProducts = products.Where (p => p.CategoryId == 2).ToArray();
var others = products.Except(categoryProducts);
```

or you can also use groupBy in one sequential go.

```
   var productGroup= product.GroupBy(p => p.CategoryId == 2);
   var category2Products = productGroups.First(p => p.Any(x=> x.CategoryId==2));
   var others = productGroups.Except(category2Products);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ILookup<bool, Product> categorizedProducts = products.ToLookup(p => (p.CategoryId == 2));

IEnumerable<Product> category2Products = categorizedProducts[true];
IEnumerable<Product> nonCategory2Products = categorizedProducts[false];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a sort:

```
List<Products>.OrderByDescending(p => p.CategoryID == 2);
```